# AWT program stuck suddently, and cannot find out the reason;

Tags: java, jvm, awt

Our java AWT program stuck suddently(cannot handle any GUI events);
Further check windows Task Explorer. The momery space is normal, and no CPU consume;|
jre version 1.7.0_45

The stack info as following;
Cannot find dead lock;
there are ONLY two active threads; one is parse regex expression, the other is native method call for awt; I cannot imagine what codes that lead to this current status. no cpu and momery consume, no lock waiting, and system have not-yet crashed;
Furthermore, While i try to jmap -heap:b,file='xxxx'pid to get dump file. and jmap also stuck. even I wait for around 3 hours, Still no any result; Anyway, it is another question, it will be better if anyone know the reason;

```
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 38: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 37: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 1: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 36: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 35: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 34: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 33: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 32: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 31: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 30: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 29: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 28: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=503 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Runnable) @bci=56, line=1266 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=4, line=1247 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=1, line=1349 (Interpreted frame)
 - editor.ctl.BJTextField.setText(java.lang.String) @bci=20 (Interpreted frame)
 - gui.frame.BJDialog.case(lib.sql.SqlTable, java.lang.String) @bci=98 (Interpreted frame)
 - gui.frame.BJDialog.Z() @bci=197 (Interpreted frame)
 - gui.frame.BJDialog.ro() @bci=71 (Interpreted frame)
 - gui.frame.BJDialog.rn() @bci=37 (Interpreted frame)
 - prog.dialog.relogin.Relogin.<init>(java.lang.String) @bci=15 (Interpreted frame)
 - prog.u.a(int, boolean) @bci=1552 (Interpreted frame)
 - prog.u.a(int) @bci=3 (Interpreted frame)
 - prog.u$a.run() @bci=44 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 27: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(java.net.DatagramPacket) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(java.net.DatagramPacket) @bci=2, line=114 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(java.net.DatagramPacket) @bci=290, line=786 (Interpreted frame)
 - lib.serv.a.a.if() @bci=31 (Interpreted frame)
 - editor.a.a.run() @bci=6 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 22: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - sun.java2d.d3d.D3DScreenUpdateManager.run() @bci=44, line=436 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 21: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=226 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=68, line=2082 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take() @bci=132, line=220 (Compiled frame)
 - javax.swing.TimerQueue.run() @bci=20, line=171 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 20: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - sun.awt.image.GifFrame.dispose() @bci=26, line=670 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.awt.image.GifImageDecoder.readImage(boolean, int, int) @bci=11, line=458 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.awt.image.GifImageDecoder.produceImage() @bci=487, line=212 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch() @bci=51, line=269 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop() @bci=33, line=205 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run() @bci=5, line=169 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 19: (state = IN_JAVA)
 - java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(java.util.regex.Matcher, int, int, java.lang.CharSequence) @bci=124, line=4166 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(java.util.regex.Matcher, int, java.lang.CharSequence) @bci=54, line=4132 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(java.util.regex.Matcher, int, java.lang.CharSequence) @bci=44, line=3408 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.regex.Matcher.search(int) @bci=86, line=1199 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.regex.Matcher.find() @bci=65, line=592 (Compiled frame)
 - editor.ctl.BJTextField.paste() @bci=166 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$PasteAction.actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) @bci=11, line=1363 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(javax.swing.Action, javax.swing.KeyStroke, java.awt.event.KeyEvent, java.lang.Object, int) @bci=132, line=1664 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(javax.swing.KeyStroke, java.awt.event.KeyEvent, int, boolean) @bci=72, line=2878 (Compiled frame)
 - javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(java.awt.event.KeyEvent, boolean) @bci=111, line=2925 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) @bci=51, line=2841 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Component.processEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=121, line=6282 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Container.processEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=18, line=2229 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=581, line=4861 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=42, line=2287 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=2, line=4687 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(java.awt.Component, java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=7, line=1895 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) @bci=63, line=762 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) @bci=140, line=1027 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(java.awt.Component, java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=154, line=899 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=1548, line=727 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=144, line=4731 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=42, line=2287 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=19, line=2719 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=2, line=4687 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(java.awt.AWTEvent, java.lang.Object) @bci=41, line=735 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(java.awt.EventQueue, java.awt.AWTEvent, java.lang.Object) @bci=3, line=103 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue$3.run() @bci=12, line=694 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue$3.run() @bci=1, line=692 (Compiled frame)
 - java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.security.PrivilegedAction, java.security.AccessControlContext) @bci=0 (Compiled frame)
 - java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(java.security.PrivilegedAction, java.security.AccessControlContext, java.security.AccessControlContext) @bci=28, line=76 (Compiled frame)
 - java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(java.security.PrivilegedAction, java.security.AccessControlContext) @bci=6, line=87 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue$4.run() @bci=11, line=708 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue$4.run() @bci=1, line=706 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.security.PrivilegedAction, java.security.AccessControlContext) @bci=0 (Compiled frame)
 - java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(java.security.PrivilegedAction, java.security.AccessControlContext, java.security.AccessControlContext) @bci=28, line=76 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=73, line=705 (Compiled frame)
 - editor.ai.dispatchEvent(java.awt.AWTEvent) @bci=26 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(int) @bci=245, line=242 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(int, java.awt.Conditional, java.awt.EventFilter) @bci=35, line=161 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(int, java.awt.Conditional, java.awt.Component) @bci=11, line=150 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(int, java.awt.Conditional) @bci=4, line=146 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(java.awt.Conditional) @bci=3, line=138 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run() @bci=9, line=91 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 16: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent() @bci=52, line=543 (Compiled frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(int) @bci=51, line=211 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(int, java.awt.Conditional, java.awt.EventFilter) @bci=35, line=161 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(int, java.awt.Conditional, java.awt.Component) @bci=11, line=150 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(int, java.awt.Conditional) @bci=4, line=146 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(java.awt.Conditional) @bci=3, line=138 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run() @bci=9, line=91 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 15: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop() @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run() @bci=49, line=299 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 14: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=503 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run() @bci=32, line=287 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 13: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=135 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=151 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.java2d.Disposer.run() @bci=3, line=145 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=744 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 8: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 7: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 6: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=135 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=151 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=16, line=189 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 5: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=503 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=46, line=133 (Compiled frame)
```

Comment: The main thread probably threw an exception you didn’t catch for display.

Comment: Also you can use VisualVM to inspect.

Comment: Are you sure that no CPU is consumed? According to your stack trace, the AWT event thread is in the middle of a regex match operation. Looks like an instance of *catastrophic backtracking* to me.

Comment: On the other hand, there are concurrent operations on a `BJTextField` happening. So it might also be a thread safety issue.

Comment: Today, I met this case again; This time, I can see the CPU was exhaused, and also can dump file; then i find out the reason that a regex expression parse problem that lead non-stop loop;
But i STILL have probelm why there are no CPU consume at last time; i found the AWT is Minimized state at last time；the whole Java program will stop, while AWT is Minimized state？

Comment: The reason is Catastrophic Backtracking problem for regex expression to parse a Large String.